# Chrome thinks it's IE and is evaluating conditionals

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, conditional-statements

Maybe I misunderstand how CSS Conditional Comments work, but I thought the bit in the middle of the conditional would only show up for IE... however Chrome and Firefox are both evaluating it, and having the left margin be 35px not -20px... What am I missing?

```
.policies li li { margin-left: -20px; }
<!--[if IE]>
.policies li { margin-left: 45px; }
.policies li li { margin-left: 35px; }
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditional comments only work in HTML, not CSS.  A common technique is to load a separate external stylesheet just for IE.  Lately I've taken to just loading a single one for IE <= 8 and then using hacks inside that stylesheet to target IE 6 / 7 / 8 respectively.

Comment: Dur. Now I feel dumb... I knew this... just haven't had to do conditionals in a long time.

Comment: Don't sweat it. It's dumb that we devs have to use these in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
.policies li { margin-left: 45px; }
.policies li li { margin-left: 35px; }
```

into separate file like `styles-ie.css`, then include it in your page after all common CSS files and wrap in a conditional comment:

```
<!--[if IE]>

  <link to your styles-ie.css />

<![endif]-->
```

Here is a [Microsoft's reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).